# Configurate python dictionary from outsource file

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following lines of code:

```
param0 = {
    'max_depth': 3,
    'eta': 0.075,
    'objective': 'binary:logistic',
    'min_child_weight': 5,
    'silent': 1,
    'eval_matric': "auc",
    'subsample': 0.6,
    'gamma': 0.5,
}
```

Which defines a pythons dictionary (for a ml model, if it interests anyone). I would like to know what is the most elegant way (and simple) to create this `param0` dictionary parameter from an outsource file. (i.e. from an xml file, json file or just a simple text file that i can configure outside the program).

1. **I'd need to know how the outsource file will look like (structure).**
2. **I need to know the code reading the outsource file.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elegance is subjective, but from a point of practicality, you'd store/load this as JSON data, assuming your dictionary doesn't hold other python objects besides lists, strings, and dicts in its values.

`config.json`

```
{
    "max_depth": 3,
    "eta": 0.075,
    "objective": "binary:logistic",
    "min_child_weight": 5,
    "silent": 1,
    "eval_matric": "auc",
    "subsample": 0.6,
    "gamma": 0.5,
}
```

Note that the [JSON spec](http://json.org) requires strings to be delimited by *double quotes* (single quotes don't fly). Keep JSON's syntax, and allowed datatypes in mind when creating/editing your file.

Code to read `config.json`, using python's `json` module.

```
import json

with open('config.json') as f:
    param0 = json.load(f)
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I need a list of tuples? I will add the following in the question.

Comment: @EranMoshe `param0 = list(json.load(f).items())`.

Comment: Wow. I just rewrite it all as list of lists. Which was wrong. You got it right. Thanks a lot!